# How to get the value of a RadComboBox when it's in a RadGrid?

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

I'd like to be able to access the value of the item chosen from the radcombobox in the code behind.  What can I write to access it when the user clicks insert?

(Please note that the comboboxes are dynamically generated so I cannot select a specific box)

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="UserCol" HeaderText="proto user" DataField="UserID">
      <EditItemTemplate>
              <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false">
               </telerik:RadComboBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

update: what I mean to say by 'dynamically generated' is that the Radgrid has a button called "add new record".  Everytime this button is clicked, a new radcombobox is generated.  The user may generate any number of them at runtime.

Comment: ..."(Please note that the comboboxes are dynamically generated so I cannot select a specific box)"......The combobox in your question is not dynamically generated, it is hardcoded! Clarify what you like to achieve and show the relevant code not something irrelevant to the question otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: Could you please provide your code, which was added radcombobox dynamically in page?

Comment: use this event protected void gridiew1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e){}

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your own other question asked the day before. I have provided an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753472